# Python Tkinter Avoid using "root" name in lower level function

Tags: python, tkinter

Inspired by this 300+ vote closed Q&A: [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application), I'm looking to avoid explicitly using `root` in a function within a class. I think it should be implicitly declared through `self` or `parent` or something like that. Here is the code in question:

I have this code...

```
        self.label_this = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_last = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_total = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Label(count_frame, textvariable=self.label_this, \
                 font=(None, MON_FONTSIZE)).pack(anchor=tk.W)
        tk.Label(count_frame, textvariable=self.label_last, \
                 font=(None, MON_FONTSIZE)).pack(anchor=tk.W)
        tk.Label(count_frame, textvariable=self.label_total, \
                 font=(None, MON_FONTSIZE)).pack(anchor=tk.W)
        self.update_cnt_labels()
```

Then later on...

```
        ''' Get list of Window ID's on monitor now '''
        new_windows = self.windows_on_monitor(new_windows)
        new_windows_cnt = len(new_windows) / WIN_CNT
        if self.old_windows_cnt == new_windows_cnt :
            FlashMessage (self.label_this, "No new windows to remove...", \
                          3, 750, 250)
            self.update_cnt_labels()
            return
```

Then later on...

```
class FlashMessage:
    def __init__(self, widget, message, count=5, on=500, off=300):

        self.delay_show (1, widget, message)
        for i in range(count):
            self.delay_show (on, widget, "")
            self.delay_show (off, widget, message)

    def delay_show(self, ms, widget, message):
        root.after(ms, widget.set(message))
        root.update_idletasks()
```

I want to avoid using `root` in the last two lines and use `self` or something similar.

My program call chain is something like:

- the traditional: `root = tk.Tk()`
- bunch of mainline initialization stuff.
- the class: `ResizingCanvas(mycanvas)`
- mainline function: `popup(event)` which is bound to `<ButtonPress-1>`
- Dynamically formatted `menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)`
- the class: `RemoveNewWindows()`
- the function: `remove()`
- the class: `FlashMessage()` (show above)
- the function: `self.delay_show()` (shown above)

Each class and function has haphazard `self`, positional parameters, `*args` and `**kwargs` which mostly serve no purpose. Indeed even the `__init__` above might be unnecessary. This is a result of copying code all over stack overflow.

Every second word in the program seems to be `self` but the word `parent`  is only used in the class `ResizingCanvas()`. Do I have to propagate `parent` down the call list and use it somehow?

Comment: I would say that the Tkinter root window is a perfectly valid use of a global variable; after all, you can't have more than one of them (without all sorts of problems).  On the other had, neither of the uses of `root` in the code you posted actually need the root window, those are methods that could be invoked on any widget you happen to have handy, without any difference in effect.

Comment: `explicitly is better then implicitly` - I would send `root` to every class which will need it later and keep as `self.root` or `self.parent` or `self.master`. Next time you can send other widget as parent and use this class in other window (Toplevel) or inside some widget (not directly in main window).

Comment: @furas Yes I'm extensively using `Toplevel` within `Toplevel` throughout the program. However `self.topevel.update_idletasks()` is not working as it has no attribute or whatever the error message is.

Comment: then show full error message in question.

Comment: @furas I've added more code to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `after` and `update_idletasks` on any widget. There are many such functions that can be called on any widget but which have a global effect.

In your case, you'll need to pass some widget into the `FlashMessage` constructor and save the reference. You can then use the reference to call the functions.

You're passing something called `widget` that doesn't actually contain a widget. You need to rename it to something more appropriate (eg: `var`), and then pass in an actual widget.

(Note: you also are calling `after` incorrectly, which I've fixed in the following example)

For example:

```
class FlashMessage:
    def __init__(self, widget, var, message, count=5, on=500, off=300):
        self.widget = widget
        ...

def delay_show(self, ...):
    self.widget.after(ms, var.set, message)
    self.widget.update_idletasks()
```

Then, whenever you create an instance of `FlashMessage` you need to add a widget as the first parameter.

For example, assuming that `count_frame` is defined in the context where you create an instance of `FlashMessage` and it is an actual widget, it might look something like this:

```
if self.old_windows_cnt == new_windows_cnt :
    FlashMessage (count_frame, self.label_this, "No new windows to remove...", \
                  3, 750, 250)
    self.update_cnt_labels()
    return
```

Comment: Sorry a little too advanced for me today. After using `widget...` I get the error: `AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute 'after'` In this case `widget` is a `tk.Label` variable text string.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: that tells me that `widget` doesn't actually contain a widget. If `widget` really was a `tk.Label` you definitely would not get that error.

Comment: Sorry I got used to "widget" as meaning "thing". It is really tk.StringVar which is used to update variable text in a Label field in this instance.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: the term `widget` in the context of a tkinter application has a very specific meaning that specifically refers to a subclass of `tk.Widget` -- Buttons, Labels, etc. and not variables.

Comment: I've updated question with code that hopefully illustrates everything you need. I'll rename the field widget to object or variable or something like that.

Comment: Could I also assign the label to a name and pass that name as a widget instead of the frame? It's easier passing the frame which has a name already but I'm just curious if a named Label qualifies as a widget just as a named Frame would.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: yes, a label is a widget.

Comment: I went with the `self.count_frame` widget because it was already named and encompasses all three variable texts should they be needed later. Also instead of generic `var` I used the same name as tikinter which is `textvariable`. On a side note Python is a wonderful coding experience and I'm looking forward to the next couple / few years. TYVM for your help. The new code works perfectly and feels much better than using `root.update_idlteasks()`.